# What's the best way to fuzzy join (multiple) dataframes by multiple columns?

Tags: r, fuzzy-search, fuzzyjoin

I need to join multiple data frames, but given that the experiment ran online and participants were often sloppy when entering their ID, I added redundancy. The also had to add letters of their parents name and their zip code. I checked manually (a bit) and there's a good amount of errors. Now I need to merge by multiple columns instead of just the participant ID.

I figured that using the fuzzyjoin package makes most sense, but I'm not sure how to go about merging multiple data frames by multiple columns each? Should I just fuzzy_right_join one data frame at a time? I have 6 in total.

Many thanks!

Here's a snippet of a few to give you an idea:

```
structure(list(participant = c("107", "110", "111", "116", "140", 
"141"), Vorname_Mutter_2_Buchstaben = c("th", "ro", "mo", "es", 
"br", "gl"), Vorname_Vater_2_Buchstaben = c("al", "ha", "wa", 
"th", "he", "re"), PLZ_letzte_2_Ziffern = c(28L, 4L, 23L, 10L, 
15L, 90L), date = structure(c(1587307867.619, 1586435099.121, 
1586424077.282, 1587733915.271, 1586794445.732, 1586896454.853
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), mean_RT = c(0.658042654028436, 
0.612637426900585, 0.721700276752767, 0.532778303249097, 0.448516151241535, 
0.59286090389016)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

structure(list(participant = c("001", "240", "242", "243", "244", 
"245"), Vorname_Mutter_2_Buchstaben = c("ma", "el", "ur", "ka", 
"ja", "la"), Vorname_Vater_2_Buchstaben = c("he", "ma", "re", 
"jo", "fe", "ab"), PLZ_letzte_2_Ziffern = c(27L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 
47L, 66L), date = structure(c(1588072799.367, 1586624239.667, 
1586260007.882, 1586712365.514, 1586275669.545, 1586696526.84
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), RT_moving_variance = c(6258.46945397108, 
5172.19983111429, 5032.90280000055, 5906.46678346693, 18694.9916770777, 
7065.17254133398)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

structure(list(participant = c("1", "105", "107", "110", "111", 
"116"), Vorname_Mutter_2_Buchstaben = c("ma", "an", "th", "ro", 
"mo", "es"), Vorname_Vater_2_Buchstaben = c("he", "ce", "al", 
"ha", "wa", "th"), PLZ_letzte_2_Ziffern = c("27", "0", "28", 
"4", "23", "10"), date = structure(c(1588071580.734, 1587402995.471, 
1587306792.774, 1586434189.309, 1586422686.217, 1587732745.487
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), on_task_mean = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

structure(list(participant = c("270", "494", "261", "171", "177", 
"323"), Vorname_Mutter_2_Buchstaben = c("se", "br", "ma", "do", 
"ir", "li"), Vorname_Vater_2_Buchstaben = c("na", "th", "ar", 
"sv", "re", "ur"), PLZ_letzte_2_Ziffern = c("02", "38", "67", 
"03", "10", "07"), date = structure(c(1586187946.415, 1586212359.648, 
1586251863.165, 1586255167.624, 1586255616.763, 1586258326.743
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Alter = c(26, 
27, 21, 28, 25, 22)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data are for individual subjects: The column `PLZ_letzte_2_Ziffern` is `integer` for the first two, and `character` for the third and fourth, so you will need to convert the latter two (or all of them) to numeric.

Then you can do an iterative full join, or just use `bind_rows`. Here are two possible `tidyverse` solutions. I have named the indivual subject data `s1` through `s4`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

```r
list_of_subjects <- list(s1, s2, s3, s4) %>% 
  map(~{.x %>% 
      mutate(PLZ_letzte_2_Ziffern = as.numeric(PLZ_letzte_2_Ziffern))})

df <- list_of_subjects %>% reduce(full_join)
```

Alternatively, you can use `map_dfr`, which uses `row_bind` to output a data frame.

```r
df <- map_dfr(list(s1, s2, s3, s4), ~{
  .x %>% 
    mutate(PLZ_letzte_2_Ziffern = as.numeric(PLZ_letzte_2_Ziffern))})
```

Using the new [colwise functionality](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/colwise.html) in `dplyr` 1.0.0:

```r
df <- map_dfr(list(s1, s2, s3, s4), ~ {.x %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with("PLZ"), as.numeric))})
```

It's not very nice that the column `PLZ_letzte_2_Ziffern` is hard-coded, but it works for this particular example.

Comment: Thanks! the main problem was how to fuzzy match using multiple ID indicators at the same time (PLZ, name of the mother, name of the father, actual participant ID, date, etc.)

The mapping is nice though, will definitely use that for a cleaner code, once I figure out the fuzzy_full_join.